# VS Code Python installation and Python Interpreter not recognized

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am getting this message on the VS Code that **`"Python is not installed. Please download and install python before using the extension."`**

There is also no `*"Python Interpreter"*` to select. When I click on it it shows it empty.

I do have `Python` and `Python extension` installed and I do have `virtual environments` set up in the `Anaconda navigator` but for some reason, I am not able to use them. I tried many ways like reinstalling the Python, Anaconda, and VS Code and also the Python extension for VS code but it's not solving the issue. What could be the reason? 
I have attached a screenshot of the VS Code as well. 
[Pleae click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1r2W.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your  anaconda installed under the default path?

Comment: Yes, @alexzshl it's a default installation.

Comment: `venvlauncher.exe` is not a valid path as that's not a Python interpreter. Did you create any conda environments with the Python version specified? You can the [environment docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) to see where the extension looks for environments and interpreters.

Comment: Did you follow the official documentation, [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) ?

Comment: From the picture you give out, it seems like the VSCode even can't find 'python.exe' on your computer. So, it's better to open a cmd and type in 'python', to check whether it works or not. Maybe the system environment caused it: Although you installed the python or anaconda, you haven't added the path of them to 'PATH'. Or maybe there is something wrong with your anaconda , so it can't find 'python.exe' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many methods but none worked. So then I removed this extension `"Anaconda Extension Pack by Microsoft"` and it solved the issue. So anyone facing the same issue might try uninstalling this extension.

Answer (score 4):

I once faced similar problem and i found out that by default vs code looks for /usr/bin/python however in some cases on linux and mac the path is /usr/bin/python3 or 2 , so you can fix it by declaring python3 as default version .

open terminal and type the following command

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

check the installation using -

```
python --version
```

it should give the output as 3.x.x

Answer (score 1):

This is interpreter error. you have to click on interpreter error showing bottom right in vs code then you choose installed latest python version.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled VS Code as is - not changing existing libraries etc - and now VS Code recognises Python/ paths again. :)
After updating to Windows 11 I think it just needed a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me was adding python to the environment variables (Windows).

- Find python at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
- Copy this path
- In the file explorer right click "This PC" and select properties
- Click Advanced System Settings in the settings window that will open (blue link on the right)
- Select Environment Variable -> New -> Add the copied python path

Answer (score 0):

try clicking the vs code link 'select interpreter path' then manually set the path 'enter interpreter path' to where you saved python. select the version you installed

Answer (score 0):

I tested this problem.If you open single .py or .ipynb file, install python not working sometimes. for better experince (if you installed python correctly on your system) first install `virtualenv` by using `pip install virtualenv`, then create project folder and import files there, then run `virtualenv 'your env name for example: venv'` then open project folder in VsCode and click install python on top or python interpreter on bottom of VsCode. this works well.